# More than one words(say phrase) vector in word2vec

Tags: nlp, word2vec

Word2vec is really great. 
Now I have a pretrained model(glove.txt), I hava "machine" vector and "learning" vector, but how can I get "machine learning" vector?
Existing methods include adding "macine_learning" to corpus and training, which not works for me cause I cannot train the model with so large corpus;
Another method is get the mean of "machine" and "learning" vectors.
I wanna if there is other ways

Comment: Basic solutions: "concatenate" if you don't mind the vector length, or "add" or "average".